# SQL query with multiple conditions 3/18/20

Tags: sql

I am stuck here, I am completely brand new to SQL. I am trying to write a query with multiple conditions across multiple columns.

So I have:

```
Select *
FROM oss.v_load_summary
WHERE report_year = 'R2020'
AND origin_region IN ('NW', 'SW')
```

I would like to add two additional data filters, first in column `dest_arrival_late_group <> Canceled` 
Second, I would like to add `gl_account = OBLH & WT & OTHER & UNKNOWN`

Any support would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The restriction on `gl_account` is not clear to me.  Can you add sample data to your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT *
FROM oss.v_load_summary
WHERE
    report_year = 'R2020' AND
    origin_region IN ('NW', 'SW') AND
    dest_arrival_late_group <> 'Canceled' AND
    gl_account IN ('OBLH', 'WT', 'OTHER', 'UNKNOWN');
```